# Rendering Multiple Materials on single Mesh

Tags: unity-game-engine, shader

In Unity3D I try to render a creature and display an outline when it is selected.

The creature alone is rendered fine:

[image: Image of creature]

I downloaded an [Outline Shader on Github](https://github.com/Shrimpey/UltimateOutline) and applied it as a second material to my mesh:

[image: Image of Renderer Settings]

With the expanded materials looking like this:

[image: Image of Expanded Materials]

However, the result is not at all as expected:

[image: Wrong Combination of Materials]

Without knowing much about materials and shaders, I tried fiddling around and found out that if I change the Rendering Mode of the Standard material to transparent the result looks fine:

[image: Right Rendering Result]

But now the creature alone renders in a kind of strange way where the limbs are overlapping the body:

[image: Wrong rendering of creature]

What is the correct way to achieve what I'm trying to do? Do you have resources where I can read more?

Comment: Looks like your other material(s) have been set as "transparent" as well.

Comment: What do you mean by "other materials(s)"? I set the material (BluePBR) of the creature to transparent. (In image 3 you can see the rendering mode i changed being marked.

Comment: If the creature is set to transparent, you'll get the effect shown in your last image. The whole idea of "transparent" is that the Z buffer isn't affected, so subsequent draws overwrite or are blended with whatever was there to start with. You need multiple materials (outline and the BluPBR), or to get your hands dirty in the shaders.

Comment: Did you try on your Outline Material to rather set the MainColor to fully transparent and leave the main material as it was? I don't nkow the shaders but your PBR would require a vertex based depth test in order to work correctly. However, in general: You shouldn't have to make any material transparent just to get it to work together with something else .. it affects the rendering performance a lot!

Comment: @3Dave I have 2 separate materials, but when I apply both of them. Only one of them shows.

Comment: @derHugo I tried setting the main color to transparent, but the result is the same. I don't want to change the standard shader for my PBR, because I want the outline to work with different shaders too. If I understand you correctly I have to get into the outline shader and prevent it from drawing over the PBR, right? I will try my luck by using Google, but I would appreciate it if someone can provide some keywords if there are some specific terms for it.

Answer (score 2):

The problem with your setup is the Render Queue. Transparent objects are rendered after opaque ones so your outline just draws on top of the creature. If you want to change the rendering order you have to treat the object with an outline as a "special" opaque object (eg. draw normal objects, draw outline, draw creature).

Here are a couple of alternatives:

1. Use `Cull Front` - This shader is basically drawing a bigger copy of the object on top of the original, like a shell. Cull Front makes it so it draws the back, instead of the front, of the shell which is behind the object.
2. Use the stencil buffer to mark the region where the original object is drawn and skip it when you draw the outline.

Below is a modified version of your shader (removed second color pass and surface shader pass since you don't use them). This is the stencil buffer option. If you want to try the other one, remove the first pass, the stencil block in the second pass and replace `Cull Back` with `Cull Front`.

```
Shader "Outlined/UltimateOutline"
{
    Properties
    {
        _Color("Main Color", Color) = (0.5,0.5,0.5,1)       

        _FirstOutlineColor("Outline color", Color) = (1,0,0,0.5)
        _FirstOutlineWidth("Outlines width", Range(0.0, 2.0)) = 0.15        

        _Angle("Switch shader on angle", Range(0.0, 180.0)) = 89
    }
    CGINCLUDE
    #include "UnityCG.cginc"

    struct appdata {
        float4 vertex : POSITION;
        float4 normal : NORMAL;
    };

    uniform float4 _FirstOutlineColor;
    uniform float _FirstOutlineWidth;

    uniform float4 _Color;
    uniform float _Angle;

    ENDCG

    SubShader{              
        Pass {
            Tags{ "Queue" = "Transparent-1" "IgnoreProjector" = "True" }
            ZWrite Off
            Stencil {
                Ref 1
                Comp always
                Pass replace
            }
            ColorMask 0
        }

        //First outline
        Pass{
            Tags{ "Queue" = "Transparent" "IgnoreProjector" = "True" "RenderType" = "Transparent" }
            Stencil {
                Ref 1
                Comp NotEqual
            }

            Blend SrcAlpha OneMinusSrcAlpha
            ZWrite Off
            Cull Back      //Replace this with Cull Front for option 1
            CGPROGRAM

            struct v2f {
                float4 pos : SV_POSITION;
            };

            #pragma vertex vert
            #pragma fragment frag

            v2f vert(appdata v) {
                appdata original = v;

                float3 scaleDir = normalize(v.vertex.xyz - float4(0,0,0,1));
                //This shader consists of 2 ways of generating outline that are dynamically switched based on demiliter angle
                //If vertex normal is pointed away from object origin then custom outline generation is used (based on scaling along the origin-vertex vector)
                //Otherwise the old-school normal vector scaling is used
                //This way prevents weird artifacts from being created when using either of the methods
                if (degrees(acos(dot(scaleDir.xyz, v.normal.xyz))) > _Angle) {
                    v.vertex.xyz += normalize(v.normal.xyz) * _FirstOutlineWidth;
                }
                else {
                   v.vertex.xyz += scaleDir * _FirstOutlineWidth;
                }

                v2f o;
                o.pos = UnityObjectToClipPos(v.vertex);
                return o;
            }

            half4 frag(v2f i) : COLOR{
                return _FirstOutlineColor;
            }
        ENDCG
        }
    }
    Fallback "Diffuse"
}
```